# How to rewrite path to my server?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am using nginx to add a subdomain to my main domain. Problem is that proxy to my other servers index is myip/folder/index.php
i made rewrite rule in my add host file that when I try to reach subdomain.mydomain.com it redirect to myip/folder/index.php but full path to index is visible. How can I hide the path in my add host file?
my add host file looks like this:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name subdomain.mydomain.com;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.0/;
rewrite ^/$ http://subdomain.mydomain.com/folder/index.php# permanent;
}
```

}

Comment: It appears that your `location` parameter `/` is the main problem. You want to replace the slash with a wildcard that will match all. The syntax you used is intended for sending default files like index.php.

Comment: I tried to change `/` parameter by folder but still i can see full path.

Answer (score 1):

The `rewrite` directive can be used in four ways. The `permanent` modifier performs an external redirect using the http 301 response code. An external redirect is usually visible to the user by modifying the URL address bar in their browser.

What you want to do is an *internal redirect* which performs the transformation invisibly to the user.

However, the `proxy_pass` directive is capable of performing simple transformations without needing to use the `rewrite` directive.

Try:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.0/folder/;
}
```

This will silently prefix `/folder/` before sending the URI upstream.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) and [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: I tried to do as you sugested but i ger 404 eror directory listed is disabled. Maybe there is other solution without enabling it?

Comment: At the moment all i tried : `server {
listen 80;
server_name subdomain.mydomain.com;
location /folder/ {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.0/folder;

}
}` But it didt work i still can see full path to my index